# Why it is not possible to set a recurring weekly electronic money transfer to a 3rd party?

Tags: united-states, banking, money-transfer

I am trying to set up a weekly recurring electronic money transfer (EFT/ACH) order to a 3rd party's checking account. It happens that 6 banks (so far) would not allow that. It seems like my options are either use the bill-pay feature, which will sent a check over regular mail, use wire transfer, which is not free, or do this manually every week, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

So it makes me wonder, why I can set such an order if I am the owner of the destination account, but not if the owner is a 3rd party? Is there a US bank that allows such order?

Note that the order features required are:

1. A *weekly recurring* order,
2. To a *private 3rd party* recipient, and
3. To a *specific bank*

Comment: Ask your bank. Mine support recurring scheduled payment. I used that for mortgage payments for many years. And I'm receiving one such payment from a friend paying down what they borrowed from me.

Comment: @keshlam - thanks. What bank do you use, if I may ask? As noted in the question, I already asked at 6 banks... My guess is that since your transfer was to a financial institution, it was OK with your bank. My transfer is to a private person.

Comment: The country is clearly stated in the question and in the tag. I will check credit unions as well.

Comment: Sorry! Missed it somehow.

Comment: As I say, I'm currently getting a transfer between two individual accounts, and I believe it's running on autopay . My accounts are in credit unions plus one local bank -- I won't say which for security reasons, sorry.

Comment: Possible factor: Mine is monthly. Many banks have a limit on how many outgoing EFTs can be made per month per account; for one of mine that number is 6. Weekly _could_ consume 5 of those in one month, so your bank might not be allowing it for that reason. Might be worth trying monthly instead.

Comment: Thanks. With the banks I checked there is no such option at all.